# How to solve this error on live server for laravel?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have installed this package success locally `composer require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer`, but when I tried to install on the live server I got this errors

```
no@zz607:/var/www/html$  composer require spatie/laravel-image- 
optimizer
Using version ^1.4 for spatie/laravel-image-optimizer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 544395264) (tried to 
allocate 20480 bytes) in 
/usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php on line 321

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 544395264) (tried to allocate 
 20480 bytes) in 
 /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php on line 321
```

server info 
[image]

Comment: this my server info
CPU:
1 vCore
RAM:
1024 MB
Storage:
25 GB SSD

Comment: What is the OS and PHP  version ?

Comment: PHP 7.2 GNU/Linux

Comment: You enabled swapfile  ? you using apache or nginx?

Comment: how do i check it?

Comment: Try it: install `htop` and run it, and give me screenshot.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrVrU.png

Comment: I'll try to respond with the solution, I hope I can help you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is related to the probable fact of having only 1gb of RAM and not having memory swap, so let's create and enable it to take some time off at the time of composer execution.

Folow this steps:

**1)** Creating **1gb** memory **swapfile**:

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile

$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
```

> This command created the `/swapfile` file with 1GB in size.

**2)** Configuring file to swap:

```
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile

$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

**3)** Enable swap:

```
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To see result you can run `free -m` or see on `htop`

**Example: `$ sudo free -m`**

```
              total       usada       livre    compart.  buff/cache  disponível
Mem.:          7664        1052        3436          56        3175        6259
Swap:          1024           0        1024
```

**Example: `$ sudo swapon --show`**

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   1G   0B   -2
```

Test please.

Comment: `no@zz607:/var/www/html$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile 1000000 bs=1024
dd: unrecognized operand ‘1000000’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
`

Comment: i have got this error while run dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile 1000000 bs=1024

Comment: @محمدمصطفي sory, test again

Comment: I have run all command, but i can't deploy anything I get this error,
`no@zz607:/var/www/html$ sudo git pull origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': username99
Password for 'https://username99@github.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 4 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/aekraes/zuxweb
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   69b12f4..b6ffb44  master     -> origin/master
`

Comment: `Updating 6cdf9f2..b6ffb44
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 composer.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting`

Comment: could you please fix this, this a live server, i can't deploy any updates now :(

Comment: oh, I think I have a problem with `composer.json` file,
 how I can recover the current permission for this file at the live server?

Comment: @محمدمصطفي to see you can run `ls -aos /you_root_project_folder` to change you run `chmod 755 -R /you_root_project_folder` 755 define all permitions on root, and read write to desgined users.

Comment: I was using an XAMPP on Mac, and trying to use Composer to install Drush. It is a tangle, and the memory error tripped us up for a couple of days. Doing your fix to add the swapfile worked though.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 33):

You should not call `composer require` or `composer update` on production server - you should run it locally, verify that everything works fine, and commit generated `composer.lock` with your project. Then on production server you need to run only `composer install --no-dev` - it will install all non-dev dependencies defined in lock file. `composer install` is much faster and uses fraction of RAM required by `composer require` or `composer update`, so it should work fine even on server with low memory. It also gives you more control on version of libraries installed on production server, so you can test app more reliable.

Comment: This is the best answer, should be the accepted answer. Thanks @rob006 !

Comment: The problem with this answer is that composer doesn't work with composer install, it will throws an error: Invalid argument shopware-pwa/shopware-pwa. Use "composer require shopware-pwa/shopware-pwa" instead to add packages to your composer.json.

Comment: Oddly, `composer install --no-dev -vvv` is working for me locally but that same command on my remote server produces error "Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update."

Comment: @Ryan You prod server may miss some PHP extensions.

Comment: Locking PHP to version 7.4 helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878435/470749