# Laravel composer install giving error "Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages please run composer update"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have been writing laravel code for quite sometime. Currently, I tried cloning a project from github and editing locally. I installed composer in my project directory but a vendor folder was not included, I tried to run `composer install` but I gives me this error

```
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update
```

How do I resolve this?

Note: I have tried running `composer update` on previous clones and that didn't work.

Comment: try to run `composer update --lock`

Comment: remove the composer.lock file from the repository and add it to .gitignore . Since you're doing a new installation, just delete the file and the vendor folder and do composer install

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thanks very much!

Comment: Putting `composer.lock` in the `.gitignore` should never be done, as you SHOULD absolutely put that file under version control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this problem with this command:

```
composer self-update --1
```

It probably works because at time that the project was developed, composer was on another version and when change the Major version from 1 to 2 the compatibility was broke. With this command you downgrade composer and probably going to solve this

Answer (score 102):

Run this command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: it's work for Ubuntu also

Comment: Thanks, composer install --ignore-platform-reqs worked for me.

Comment: @M_R_K it depends on the use, if your project is old and you just want it to run as expected (private purpose), you have to tag it, or else, ain't no world this is running.

Answer (score 24):

> Disclaimer, this solution will not fix the issue for PHP 8 projects.

In most cases this happens because of PHP 8 (In my case it was GitHub CI actions automatically started using PHP 8 even though my project is php 7.4)

If you have multiple PHP installations (E.g. 7.4 and 8 on the same server), this is how you can fix it.

Specify your php version in your composer.json file

```
"config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.3"
        }
    },
```

If you have the lock file already committed, run composer update after you adding above line in to the composer.json and then commit the new lock file. (Please be aware composer update will upgrade your packages to latest versions)

Answer (score 8):

You should try running `composer update --lock` that will update all packages and recreate the compose.lock file.

Either you can delete the composer.lock file and run `composer install` that will also recreate the .lock file.

This resolved my issue.

Comment: thanks, buddy! this helps `Either you can delete the composer.lock file and run composer install that will also recreate the .lock file.`

Answer (score 7):

I had this error with Github Actions trying to deploy a Laravel app, this is probably different than the OP's case but none of the suggestions worked for me.  Adding my answer here just in case there is someone else out there with a similar problem to mine.

I had to disable `-q` in Github Actions and see that it was complaining about extensions not being installed.

Make sure your `require` section of composer's php extensions matches the `extensions:` in your github action file for `shivammathur/setup-php@v2` and it will deploy again

Comment: Me too. Turns out GitHub's default action for Laravel uses PHP 8.0, whereas my Laravel is on PHP 8.1. Thanks for the tip, I could see the right error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this problem is occuring in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. This is due to some missing packages.

I ran the following commands to install some packages then rerun Composer install and its working properly. The commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Then rerun composer install

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error deploying another project with composer, but the problem was a missing php extension.

I understand you solve your problem but for anyone seeing the same error message, here is a general guidance :

The error message `Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update` is shown each time there is a conflict during the dependency solving step of composer install. (see [the relevant part in composer source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/d9454938b0644fd9fa57ee6e63c4c285d8b40792/src/Composer/Installer.php#L630-L653))

It doesn't inform on the real problem though, and it could be hard to guess.

To get the exact explanation you can add `--verbose` option to `composer install` command (the option is available to any composer command [(see the doc)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options)) : `composer install --verbose`

It will give you the full message explaining what exactly is preventing composer install from completing (package version conflict, missing php extension, etc.), then you'll be able to fix the problem.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've just come across of this error when I tried to run my **Laravel 7** project which required **php v7.*** with **php v8**. As I forgot my php version I just tried bunch of composer command, but just got error after error.

Anyway, to solve this just downgrade/upgrade php version as required. Just search how to do that in youtube.
you can see your project required php version in `composer.json` file (just if you wonder)

Also you can try following way (But though it didn't worked for me, seems it helped quite some people)

-- Open `composer.json` file and change php version to something like this: `"php": "^7.3|^8.1"`

-- Then run `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with my cakephp project in garuda linux (arch based)

### Fix :

1. Install php-intl using `sudo pacman -S php-intl`
2. Enable php intl by editing php config ( in my case `/etc/php/php.ini` ) .
   add `extension=intl` or uncomment the existing one
3. restart apache or whatever you are using